# Replacing ViewPager With MenuItem Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

[image]

I have an `Activity` in which total 4 `fragments` are there . Out of 4 , 3 fragments are integrated as Tabs with `Viewpager` , the 4th one is in the Menu as favourite icon . I want to open Favourite `Fragment` on favourite icon click from any of the 3 tabs .

When i put the below code

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_manage_profile) {
            Fragment newFragment = new FragmentHomeProfile();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container2, newFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

1. In `Activity`

It Appears as a bottom sheet Fragment.

2.In Any of the `fragment` (for ex Tab2)

It Overlaps the Tab2 Fragment , and favourite and Tab2 fragment contents are visible .

What i Want ?

It Should totally replace `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` view and should only show Favourite `Fragment` contents.

Answer (score 0):

Use a FrameLayout

1. Tabs and viewpager are part of a fragment will be added in the frame layout.
2. whenever fav button is pressed it easily be replaced in frame layout

why are you using childfragmentmanager ?

try using supportfragmentmanager